# ANTLR4 add additional parsing validation

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

Let's say, I have text file:

```
Vegetable carrot,
Vegetable salad,
Fruit orange,
Fruit apple,

PRINT GetFruitCalories(orange),
PRINT GetFruitCalories(salad)
```

ANTLR can collect all those tokens.

- Let's say we want to ban vegetable-types in GetFruitCalories method.
- This method should take only fruit-args
- Antrl can check if we have number, comma, dot, (, ), new line.... (grammar) but how about "smart" type checking?
- Can we check based on prefix "Fruit" and "Vegetable", type of salad and orange?
- I would like to raise an error by Parser when I execute GetFruitCalories(salad).
- I can make visitor which will check types, but error order will be:

1. first parser checking gramma
2. my custom checking type of fruit in my visitor

I would like to combine it together, some code with errors:

```
ABCBACBAC_INVALID_TEXT1 //raise an error by grammar
Vegetable salad,
PRINT GetFruitCalories(salad), //raise an error by "smart" checking type
ABCBACBAC_INVALID_TEXT2 //raise an error by grammar
```

Errors should be displayed in order:

- raise an error by grammar
- raise an error by "smart" checking type
- raise an error by grammar

But if I do my visitor, errors from grammar parser will be executed first and I will see only:

- raise an error by grammar
- raise an error by grammar

and PRINT GetFruitCalories(salad) will be prevented because of Parser.

I use C# and after collecting all fruits and vegetables it would be nice to have an event to check those types. Most important for me is **error sequence order**. Probably, I want to make it on parser layer. Is it possible? Is any customization? Usually I just invoke method "parse". Maybe introducing c# code in grammar may help - I never tried. Event on 'CaloriesVisitor' method could be also nice.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to better understand the process of language processing here. It consists of more than just parsing (which is, simply put, a way to determine the validity of input compared to a language definition - the grammar). Parsing gives you a structure that describes the input in some way (usually a parse tree or a syntax tree). It doesn't know anything about the meaning of the individual tokens. Determining that is usually part of another step: the semantic phase.

In such a semantic phase you take the output from the parse run and apply meaning to relevant tokens, like which type was found (Fruit, Vegetable). With this knowledge you can then start to do a type validation for your function.

This separation makes it hopefully clear for you that you cannot and should not handle semantics in your parsing (syntactic) step.

Comment: I agree with you that it's good not to mix syntax parsing and smart validation like checking object type. If this is best practice I should accept it. However it doesn't solve my issue.